# How To Create Launcher For Application?

Tags: 13.04, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, I recently downloaded **Fritzing** .tar.bz2 , which I extracted it & there is one .sh file, which I have to execute everytime from terminal to run the application.

My question is, Is it possible to create a launcher of Fritzing & make it show up in Applications in Dash ? If it is, then please help me out with steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really a duplicate since it doesn't specifically ask how to do it by hand. A reply with a GUI would have been welcome

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, this is quite simple, what you want to create is a named file with a `.desktop` extension with contents like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Steam
Comment=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Exec=/usr/bin/steam %U
Icon=steam
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;Game;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/steam;
Actions=Store;Community;Library;Servers;Screenshots;News;Settings;BigPicture;Friends;
```

[image: Here is an image]

To create this file globally you can run your favorite text editor as root using `sudo`, using the terminal application. If it's a graphical editor, keep your environment clean by adding the `-H` flag:

```
sudo -H gedit
```

Browse to the `/usr/share/applications/`
directory. It should look something like this:

[image]

Select any `.desktop` file, it should look something like the `steam.desktop` example above. After you have edited it it should be close to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Fritzing
Comment=
Exec=sh [link to file]
Icon=[link to icon(not required)]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=[choose what categories you want this file to fit into such as Game,Browser ext.]
```

It is important to note that the path to the files has to be the full path. Tilde expansion won't work so you can use `~/` paths. Also if you want to run your script as root you can add `gksudo` (`gksudo` has been removed from ubuntu as of 13.04, you can install it by running the command `sudo apt-get install gksu` in the terminal) before the sh command on the `Exec=` line.

Once you have saved your file, right click, go into properties, permissions and make sure that Allow executing as file is ticked. Then restart, it may not be required though.

**Terminal way:**

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
sudo -H gedit [your chosen desktop file]
```

or

```
sudo nano [your chosen desktop file]
```

Edit it then save as what you want to call it.

```
chmod a+x [your saved desktop file]
```

You may need to restart you pc

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: dont use "sudo gedit"
use "gksu gedit" instead