# Google Chrome does not show up in dashboard

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04. I just installed Google Chrome using these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi

sudo gdebi google*
```

I do not see the Google Chrome icon in the dashboard. It looked like the program is installed in the `opt/google/chrome` directory but how do I get the program to execute or get it to show up in the Dashboard?

Any help/direction would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Melinda, have your problem solved or the icon is still not showing in the Dashboard?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I just put an UPVOTE for the response below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart your computer and the **Chrome** launcher icon will come up.

But first, check that your chrome browser installed correctly by running it via terminal.

Type `google-chrome` and press `Enter`.

if the icon still not come up after restart, create them manually. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330781/how-to-create-launcher-for-application) is the tutorial.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It did start via the terminal command.  I appreciate very much your time and help in replying.