# Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string: ' '

Tags: command-line, bashrc

Sorry I am pretty new to Linux machine, Ubuntu and Command line.

**Here is what I did:**

1. I tried to install `PhpStorm 2016.3.2` on Linux machine (Ubuntu) by downloading the `.gz` file from JetBrains site.
2. I extracted the `PhpStorm-2016.3.2.tar.gz` file inside `/home/[USERNAME]/apps/phpstorm/` folder.
3. I went inside `bin/` folder and typed command line  `./phpstorm.sh` using Terminal.
4. It opens the PhpStorm application, but..

**Error message:**

It shows the following message while opening the app:

> Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string:  ' '

**Problem:**

1. Application cannot stay open unless this Terminal stays open.
2. PhpStorm's icon is not created on my machine, so every time if I want to open PhpStorm, I have to open Terminal and type `./phpstorm.sh`.

**Questions:**

1. While I was looking for solution, I got a feedback that I need to edit .bashrc file to make it executable in that path. What does it mean?
2. Do I have to modify the path inside "jediterm-bash.in"–> function load_interactive_configs?

[bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnM8P.jpg)

Comment: Hello, welcome to AskUbuntu. Avoid using screen grabs, instead, copy the text of the shell function to the post under a code block.

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure what you meant.. Can you please explain more visually? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your *real* question is [How To Create Launcher For Application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330781/how-to-create-launcher-for-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Comment: Wow. so we have to manually create a launcher for the third party app? Coming from Windows background, everything is so new to me. :)

Comment: I get this when launching Arduino IDE via ssh -Y (xterm), and true, the terminal must be kept open, but the fact is that it works anyway.