# Create applications that performs keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have been wondering if it is possible to create an application whose sole purpose is to perform a specific keyboard shortcut assigned to it when its icon is clicked.

I believe that this can be done using the file that the keyboard shortcut is saved in. However, unfortunately I could not find a folder that might contain such files. Kindly respond as soon as possible if you have any idea how to do such thing because I am kind of in a hurry.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such an effect using a small and very useful command line tool, `xdotool`. For example, the command

```
sleep 0.3s; xdotool key ctrl+x
```

will trigger a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> keypress when executed.

Include these command in [a custom launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330781/how-to-create-launcher-for-application) file to obtain a clickable item.

The `sleep` command introduces a small 300 ms delay before executing the command. This will decrease the chance that the keypress is discarded by the keyboard buffer. To have this work directly in a `.desktop` file, write your `Exec=` line as:

```
Exec=sh -c "sleep 0.3s; xdotool key ctrl+x"
```

In the `.desktop` file, you also can specify your icon.